# Why is dwm.exe using so much memory?

Tags: windows-7, memory, aero, dwm

I've scoured the web, but I'm sick of reading "scan your computer for viruses" and "upgrade your RAM" on answers to similar questions to this. I understand that dwm.exe is for (simply put) caching bitmaps for things like Aero-peek and similar, but as far as I have read it shouldn't be using vast amounts of memory.

My colleague and I both have 4GB of RAM, Core 2 Duo, blah, blah -- essentially they're pretty capable. His dwm.exe is running at around 30mb, mine is currently running at about half a gig, though it does fluctuate quite a lot. This is the same while running the exact same applications (currently Zend studio, FireFox (with firemin - low memory usage), Outlook). Every so often I will get a notification asking me if I want to switch to Aero Basic because it's using too much memory, and sometimes it will just switch itself to basic and let me know why.

I know it's possible to stop it switching, but I want to know why it is using too much memory otherwise it's just papering over the cracks.

One thing to add is this *seems* to have started after a robbery on Monday, where two of my monitors were stolen, and I had to temporarily use a couple of alternative monitors. I am now using brand new monitors but the problem is the same. All drivers installed and working seemingly fine.

Any ideas why the usage is so high?

We are using windows 7 64-bit Professional.

Comment: Can you get any clues from Proccess Monitor?

Comment: What kind of information would you regard as a clue in Process Monitor? Sorry, not used it a whole lot.

Comment: You can drill down into the processes more and see what, if any other processes it is talking to.

Comment: dwm.exe doesn't actually seem to show up in procmon...?

Comment: Yeah ProcMon can be a little hairy.  How about the sysinternals tool Process Explorer?  Can you find any clues with that maybe?

Comment: How come no info on the used Theme, visual effects enabled, number of monitors and their resolutions and whether cloned or extended, etc., etc., on the respective computers? They all would seem to be highly relevant.

Comment: kreemoweet, the Theme doesn't matter (it's Aero anyway when the DWM is enabled), the transparency shader doesn't need memory, just GPU performance.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know the graphics cards used in both computers as well as how up-to-date the drivers are. E.g. if the driver doesn't support WDDM 1.1 then you'll have much higher memory usage.

Comment: 0.5 GB isn't a lot fo memory!

Comment: `dwm.exe` eating 18GB out of 32GB on Windows 10 is still a problem. I just kill it and wait a while for things to reload. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `DWM.EXE` process will consume a lot of memory when you have multiple screens and the system performance is set to the default of **Let Windows choose what's best for my computer**.  To change this:

1. Go to *Computer* -> Right click and choose *Properties*
2. Select the *Advanced* tab
3. Select the **Settings** button under the *Performance* section. This will popup the Performance Options window
4. On the first tab is *Visual Effects*.  Select `Adjust for best performance` or `Custom` (and select the feature(s) you want).

I chose `Custom` myself and selected only the `Smooth edges of fonts` to reduce memory usage from 534M to 6M with running 4 windows.

Comment: Well, if you don't enable the DWM it won't use any memory of course ;)

Comment: That's not the whole answer. I have best appearance set in the settings, and dwm.exe usually takes 80-100 MB of memory, but recently it has started sporadically spiking up to 1300 MB of RAM. If I terminate the process, it restarts automatically with normal 80 MB (and Aero style immediately applies again, so it's not like restart kills visual effects).

Comment: Thanks, this has made my computer *much* faster, especially in Eclipse. Note that it turns off 'Aero' and its transparent window effects etc.

Comment: I first tried the hint from http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001182.htm to switch from (default?) Aero style to Win basic theme - and this lowered usage (but not enough for me). Next, I tried this fix and this really seems to have helped.

Comment: @pjc50 I've recently started using Eclipse and have noticed dwm.exe taking much more memory than usual. Maybe Eclipse doesn't work well with Aero?

Comment: You can find the properties by going Start -> Run -> sysdm.cpl which seems to be the easiest way on Windows 11

Comment: Dwm was 800 - 900MB and when I turned off a bunch of this stuff, dropped to 4 - 10MB. Doesn't look as good, but Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

I use this batch code to refresh **dwm.exe**. There will be a blank screen for a second.
The **dwm.exe** RAM usage will go back to normal.

**I strongly recommend you close all of your applications to prevent program crash before executing**

```
@ECHO OFF 
taskkill /F /IM dwm.exe 
taskkill /F /IM conhost.exe
```

This must be run as Administrator.

Comment: Note that killing dwm.exe from task manager does not seem to work.

Comment: Killing dwm.exe from task manager worked for me, but both my screens went black for several minutes - basically until I found this thread on a phone when searching whether I broke it or not.

Answer (score 10):

Since I cannot comment yet, I'll add this as additional answer.
Microsoft has confirmed a memory leak in DWM.EXE: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/system-malfunction-because-memory-leak-occurs-in-dwm-exe-in-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-360aef3b-8df7-d104-552b-5fdb0f0ec990

In short, DWM.EXE leaks memory when status windows are open for a long time.

Comment: For further readers: On Windows 10, there might be another memory leak, mine dwm.exe grows every hour or so, after whole day it goes even up to 1 GB, and it still grows... After 2 weeks without hard restarting (I usually just hibernate) it was once 20 GB (YEP, even while I have just 16 GB of physical RAM)... Sad thing is, I reported this issue 2 or 3 times already, Microsoft does not care.

Comment: Seconding what @PsychoX has said above, it's at over 1.7 GB on my Windows 10 PC.

Comment: It's August 2022 and Windows 11 still need more than 1GB of RAM for the WM, guess this is not important enough to be fixed. Edit: I only keep the smooth fonts on and turn everything else off, so it's probably not about the config

Comment: So what exactly constitutes  a `status window`?  I need to get some ideas on what to look for or which windows to keep closed  ("....DWM.EXE leaks memory when status windows are open for a long time")

Answer (score 9):

There's a confirmed memory leak with Intel's graphics driver versions between 27.20.100.8587 and 30.0.101.1191 (not inclusive) which will cause `dwm.exe` to eat memory in some situations. It got up past 19GB (!!) for me before the compositor crashed. It clearly doesn't happen all the time, seeing how it took me months to notice.

As of Oct. 2022, Windows Update is still distributing a buggy driver version. Installing a [newer version](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-dch-drivers.html) from Intel will resolve the issue.

Source: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058381/graphics/graphics-for-8th-generation-intel-processors.html

Comment: Windows Update still distributes outdated driver version which has this issue. Manually updating the driver solved memory consumption.

Comment: It seems to be ok to just kill the process and wait for a ~ 1 minute, until everything loads again.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the dwm service:

1. Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and type **services.msc**.
2. Find **Desktop Window Manager Session Manager**.
3. Click **Restart** the service and see if that fixes it.

Or if you want to get rid of the process all together, just click **Stop**.

Comment: From what I understand, restarting the computer would have the same effect as restarting DWM. And would stopping DWM be a good idea, considering it's needed?

Comment: Technically yes, but here read this see if this helps any: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-dwmexe-and-why-is-it-running/

Comment: I don't see how that helps at all. **Note that I don’t recommend turning this off unless you are playing games in fullscreen mode, and even then it likely won’t help increase speed.** for starters, and I have indeed read this page already (I did Google before posting this question). I also said **Iknow it's possible to stop it switching, but I want to know why it is using too much memory otherwise it's just papering over the cracks.** and this doesn't help at all.

Comment: Starting from Windows 7 it is impossible to stop DWM (so the service doesn't show up in services.msc)

Answer (score -2):

Another speed up tip is to hold the <kbd>windows key</kbd> and press <kbd>r</kbd>, type `msconfig` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, click on `boot tab` > `advanced options` then check `mark number of processors` then click the down arrow and select max number of cores 2 is duo 4 is quad hit `ok`.

Check mark boot log and OS boot information, then in the right click `make all boot changes permanent` and make sure nothing else is open and hit `apply` then restart.
Most Microsoft windows computers only use one core by default boot settings.
This works on windows 8 and 8.1 for sure. I haven't tried it on anything before that.
Good luck :)

Comment: this really doesn't sound like a good idea to be messing with this option - especially your comment "Most Microsoft windows computers only use one core by default boot settings." !!

Answer (score -3):

i had this problem for a while and nothing really seemed to work.but i found out that after clearing my C drive, the memory usage went down.try to move unwanted programes from c to e/d drives.hope this helps you!