# Very fast Laptop Heating due to very high CPU usage by dwm.exe

Tags: windows-7, overheating, high-cpu-usage

My laptop gets heated very fast and when I check the task manager, I find dwm.exe consuming very high CPU (mostly 100%). In the beginning I found the message "The graphic adapter has been stopped and recovered".Also I am getting one error message "Cidaemon.exe has stopped working" very frequently. During this period also, cpu usage is 100% which is consumed by dwm.exe. I have run ccleaner and Kingsoft PC doctor monitor to fix the register problem but the problem has not been solved.

My display adaptor is : NVIDIA NVS 5200M.
After the driver update, I am not getting "The graphic adapter has been stopped and recovered" but dwm.exe is still consuming 100% CPU one time in about 5 mins.

Multiple restarts has not helped. 
Laptop Model: Dell Latitude E6430.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related but perhaps not a duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/428794/why-is-dwm-exe-using-so-much-memory

Comment: Which driver version are you currently using?