# Windows 10 dvm.exe over 2GB ! of RAM (6-monitors)

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have 6 low res monitors.. no 4k or anything crazy..(six @ 1280x1024) 
My DVM.exe consumes crazy amount of memory..  well over 2GB in some cases.. 
I have tried all the suggestions I could find.. most of which were from older OSs.
This seems crazy to me.. I am unable find a way to keep down to a reasonable RAM consumption...
A reboot... does help.. but grows rapidly...
I have the lastest firmware and drivers... this is not a new problem..
ANY suggestions?

-Ken

Comment: What applications are you running on these 6 screens? DWM usage is going to depend a LOT on how many windows are running, much more than how many screens.

Answer (score -1):

i'm finding the same thing - about 5 or 6 windows open, have the latest drivers. The system is a pretty recent model of Dell laptop with an intel driver. Mem usage doesn't climb really quick, hours, sometimes days if i leave it on, but it gets to 3gb.

A workaround that doesn't need a reboot is to kill it in task manager, it will relaunch and with the apps I'm using, it just reconnects to all the windows, i don't loose WM features on them.

*edit*
I have just found this: https://superuser.com/a/496506/376428

I am disabling some of the effects now, my DWM is using about 50mb, will monitor it and see if this has long term effectiveness.