# Extremely high memory usage on Desktop Window Manager

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, task-manager, window-manager

My desktop window manager is just taking too much memory for no reason. I was playing a game that had pretty average memory usage for a game (Apex Legends - 2000MB ish) before editing a word document when my fan started blasting out hot air. I checked my task manager and found this.

My task manager:

[image]

Generally, I have high memory usage on DWM, sometimes peaking around 2000MB. I have tried changing the performance settings as shown below. I running Windows 10 20H2 with an i7-9750h and 12GB of RAM which is pretty nice and should be able to handle normal loads. Any help would be appreciated.

These are my performance settings:

[image]

Comment: That's just an insane amount of memory being used.

Comment: @RaptorRV: Read the following post: [desktop window manager extremely high ram usage](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/desktop-window-manager-extremely-high-ram-usage/e3c722bd-6aa1-4b51-a43a-c32872a16c11). Somehow it might be related to video driver on your system.

Comment: @Joe I know it's insane which is why I asked the question. While I was posting this it went up to 6400 MB. I just have word, discord, and edge working.

Comment: Have you tried killing the process and starting up again?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this question here? Maybe it can help you solve your issue. 

https://superuser.com/questions/428794/why-is-dwm-exe-using-so-much-memory

Comment: @Joe I do that whenever it happens, but it happens so often that I need to find a permanent fix. Yes, I have tried everything in that solution.

Comment: @Jackdaw I install all my Nvidia drivers using GeForce experience so it's always up to date. Im checking my intel drivers right now.

Comment: @RaptorRV: I would recommend open the `Task manager` go to the `Details` tab and select to show the following columns:   Working set, Working set delta, Handlers, Threads, GDI objects, GPU, GPU engine, Dedicated GPU memory, Shared GPU memory. All those data will say you some helpful information about state of the Desktop Window Manager.

Comment: @Jackdaw I installed the latest intel driver and restarted. Currently, it seems to be behaving fine.